# Ruby 1.9.3 Dir.glob not returning NFC UTF-8 strings, returns NFD instead

Tags: ruby

When reading file names from Ruby 1.9.3, I'm seeing some odd results. For example with the following test ruby script, running in a folder containing a file with the name 'Testé.txt'

```
#!encoding:UTF-8
def inspect_string s
    puts "Source encoding: #{"".encoding}"
    puts "External encoding: #{Encoding.default_external}"
    puts "Name: #{s.inspect}"
    puts "Encoding: #{s.encoding}"
    puts "Chars: #{s.chars.to_a.inspect}"
    puts "Codepoints: #{s.codepoints.to_a.inspect}"
    puts "Bytes: #{s.bytes.to_a.inspect}"
end

def transform_string s
   puts "Testing string #{s}"
   puts s.gsub(/é/u,'TEST')
end

Dir.glob("./*.txt").each do |f|  

   puts RUBY_VERSION + RUBY_PLATFORM

   puts "Inline string works as expected" 
   s = "./Testé.txt" 
   inspect_string s
   puts transform_string s

   puts "File name from Dir.glob does not" 
   inspect_string f
   puts transform_string f

end
```

On Mac OS X Lion, I see the following results:

```
1.9.3x86_64-darwin11.4.0
Inline string works as expected
Source encoding: UTF-8
External encoding: UTF-8
Name: "./Testé.txt"
Encoding: UTF-8
Chars: [".", "/", "T", "e", "s", "t", "é", ".", "t", "x", "t"]
Codepoints: [46, 47, 84, 101, 115, 116, 233, 46, 116, 120, 116]
Bytes: [46, 47, 84, 101, 115, 116, 195, 169, 46, 116, 120, 116]
Testing string ./Testé.txt
./TestTEST.txt

File name from Dir.glob does not
Source encoding: UTF-8
External encoding: UTF-8
Name: "./Testé.txt"
Encoding: UTF-8
Chars: [".", "/", "T", "e", "s", "t", "e", "́", ".", "t", "x", "t"]
Codepoints: [46, 47, 84, 101, 115, 116, 101, 769, 46, 116, 120, 116]
Bytes: [46, 47, 84, 101, 115, 116, 101, 204, 129, 46, 116, 120, 116]
Testing string ./Testé.txt
./Testé.txt
```

The expected last line is

```
./TestTEST.txt
```

the encodings returned indicate that this is a normal UTF-8 string and yet any regexp transformations involving unicode are not being applied properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted in case this is useful for anyone else running into this:

Ruby 1.9 and 2.0 will use composed UTF-8 strings if you use UTF-8 encoding, but will not modify strings received from the OS. Mac OS X uses decomposed strings (two bytes for many common accents like é in UTF-8, which are combined for display). So file system methods will often return unexpected string formats, which are strictly UTF-8, but a decomposed form.

In order to work around this, you need to decompose them by converting from the 'UTF8-MAC' encoding to UTF-8:

```
f.encode!('UTF-8','UTF8-MAC')
```

Before using them, otherwise you may end up running checks against a decomposed string with a native ruby string which is composed.

This behaviour affects all file system calls like glob for both files and folders where a file name contains unicode characters.

Apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1235/_index.html

Comment: Although there is nothing non utf8ish about a decomposed string - it's still perfectly legal (although OS X (for legacy reasons) doesn't decompose some character strings you might expect it to)

Comment: Hmm, yes so it is a valid utf-8 string, but none of the expected ruby methods will work on it because it is decomposed. I've logged a bug to see what the official position is, but this behaviour is surprising, and I can't think why it an extra step is required when dealing with file names.

Answer (score 3):

An update to this: Ruby 2.2.0 has gained [String#unicode_normalize](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html).

```rb
f.unicode_normalize!
```

would convert the NFD-decomposed string returned from OSX' HFS+ filesystem into a NFC-composed string. You can specify `:nfd`, `:nfkc`, or `:nfkd` if you require alternative normalizations.